# Replace a string with a string out of many in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

So, I have a pandas data frame where one column contains the description of the nationality of a user and I want to replace this whole description with the country he's from.

My inputs are the df and the list of countries:

| Description | ID |
| --- | --- |
| I am from Atlantis | 1 |
| My family comes from Narnia | 2 |

```
["narnia","uzbekistan","Atlantis",...]
```

I know that:

1. I only have one country per description
2. the description contains the name of the country or does not, there is no necessity to infer the country from what he says, I only want to map [phrase containing name of country] to [country].

If I had only one country to replace I could use something like

```
df.loc[df['description'].str.contains('Atlantis', case=False), 'description'] = 'Atlantis'
```

I know that, because the country names are organised in a list, I could cycle through it and apply this to all the elements, something like:

```
for country in country_list:
  df.loc[df['description'].str.contains(country, case=False), 'description'] = country
```

but it seems to me quite *unpythonic* so I was wondering if anyone could help me finding a better way (that I'm sure exists)

The output should be:

| Description | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Atlantis | 1 |
| Narnia | 2 |

Comment: Can you share input sample data & expected output.

Comment: Use `str.extract` instead with a pattern of `'|'.join(country_list)`.

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup Added, sorry but I forgot while writing the question.

Comment: @HenryYik do you mean the pandas.series.str.extract method? doesn't it use regex? can you pass it a string, if you could give a more complete and clearer answer I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.extract`:

```
country_list = ["narnia","uzbekistan","Atlantis"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': {0: 'I am from Atlantis', 
                                   1: 'My family comes from Narnia'}, 
                   'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2}})

print (df["Description"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(country_list)})", flags=re.I))

          0
0  Atlantis
1    Narnia
```